# Store, websites Magento 2 catalog

Tags: magento2, catalog, store-view, url-key

I'm very confused. I exported all my products and saw I have the same product in default store and "no store", I mean, my catalog have the same products twice. Not sure what it causes and how this happened but one of the problems is that I cannot see the real url_key for many items, inside the product page in backend I need to switch store view and I believe sitemap is not sending the correct url_key for items. Is this scenario normal? Thank you.